# how to fade in divs with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how do  I add fade in effect(slowly coming down effect) on new divs when i click "load more" button on this fiddle ?

http://jsfiddle.net/XBNQC/10/

```
$(function(){
    $("div").slice(0, 10).show(1); // select the first ten
    $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show(200); // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
        if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
            alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) or [.slideDown()](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

```
$("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).fadeIn();//or .slideDown();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6sdUE/)</kbd> or <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6sdUE/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.slideDown](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and pass the time in millisecond.

```
$("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).slideDown(1000);
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBNQC/45/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `fadeIn` with `slow` as the first parameter:

```
$("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).fadeIn('slow');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBNQC/46/)

[jQuery fadeIn Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String)

Now I read `slowly coming down effect`, so I'm thinking maybe you don't want a `fadeIn` effect, but a `slideDown` effect?  Well, jQuery has a function for that, too:

```
$("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).slideDown('slow');
```

Again with `slow` as the first parameter.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBNQC/47/)

[Documentation on `slideDown`](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

You can even do them simultaneously:

```
$("div:hidden").slice(0, 10)
    .css('opacity', 0)
    .slideDown('slow')
    .animate({
    opacity: 1
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 'slow'
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XBNQC/48/)